# AS3 : Greensock Tweening on Variable value

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, gsap

In AS3, if I wanted to affect a Movie Clip based on a variable value I would do :

```
 var SuperTemp = "carousel";
 this[SuperTemp].alpha = 0;
```

The result would turn the carousel invisible.
How do you affect a greensock tween object with a variable value?
I thought it is something like :

```
 TweenLite.to(this.SuperTemp, .5, {alpha:0});
```

Any ideas?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to animate the String value of SuperTemp itself, so that won't work. You have to apply the tween directly to the MovieClip:

```
var mc:MovieClip = this["carousel"];
TweenLite.to(mc, .5, {alpha:0});
```

Comment: Dude.  You've cracked the code.  You're like a regular Nicolas Cage in  "National Treasure."  And no...I'm not kidding.  Thanks You.